# Unexpected results from str_detect()

Tags: r, regex, stringr

`str_detect(c("abc", "xyz"), letters))` does not return expected results.
It should be a vector of

```
[1]  TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[23] FALSE  TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

But instead it returns

```
str_detect(c("abc", "xyz"), letters))
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[23] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Why? And how do I get the desired result?

Comment: If you have some 140 terms you may try `str_detect(paste(c("abc", "xyz"), collapse="|"), letters))`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because `str_detect` recycles arguments. It's comparing `abc` against `a`, then `xyz` against `b`, then `abc` against `c`, and so on. You should paste together `abc` and `xyz` into a single character, or just supply `c("abcxyz")`, but I'm assuming this might be a simplified version of a more complex issue.

```r
library(stringr)
rgx <- paste0(c("abc", "xyz"), collapse = "")
str_detect(rgx, letters)
```

Comment: indeed, this is the rub of a more complicated problem, thanks for your reply.

I am doing a search for multiple search terms (140 of them) over many large documents of various types. 

I don't think it would be feasible to collapse all of the character vectors from readLines, read_excel, read_csv, etc into one very large string, one for each document. So maybe due to the nature of str_detect I should use lapply() to loop over all of the 140 terms?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Without knowing your larger data and what you're looking for, I'm not sure exactly how you would do it, but should work.